# Vielbein from covariant expression for the metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Suppose I have a metric tensor given by $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\mu f\partial_\nu f$. I want to obtain a vielbein $e_\mu^a$ such that $g_{\mu\nu}=e_\mu^a\eta_{ab}e_\nu^b$. I know that the vielbein is not unique, but I'd like to find a covariant expression for it. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the matrix equations:

$$ M g M^{T} = diag (-1, 1,1,1)$$

And:

$$ M M^{T} = 1$$

Another way is finding the eigenvectors $v_\mu$ that diagonalize $g$ in the right signature and normalize them to $\pm 1$

Then arrange each of the four eigenvectors in columns of a matrix, such that:

$M^a_\mu = v_\mu ^{(a)}$

This matrix is then your vielbein